# WebView loadDataWithBaseUrl - weird issue in android 4.0.3

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In my project there are two WebViews and I am switching these WebViews alternatively to get a smooth animation while loading my url. When I am using Webview.loadUrl() method, it works fine in all devices. But when I am using the same code with loadDataWithBaseUrl() then its not working in 4.0.3 but it's working fine in 2.2, 2.3, 4.0.4, 4.1 devices.

Is this a bug jumping from WebKit?
I tried so many ways to get this done but no way out. I am really frustrated and messed-up with this.

It will be so helpful if someone could show me a right way to get this done.

Comment: Could you be more specific about it not working. Does it just not load anything period? Does it throw some kind of error? Etc. Also some code snippets would help.

Comment: I am loading this webview in an Assynctask.From doinbackgroungd i am calling runonuithread and load the webview using loaddatawithbaseurl()..when i use loadurl() its working fine in 4.0.3 but loaddatawithbaseurl() its failing..

Comment: Whats the base url you have specified in the loadDataWithBaseUrl method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add these property with webview-

```
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

and can use animation because its working well for me like-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <translate 

      android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
      android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with 4.0.3 altogether with WebView animations.
What fixed it for me was removing alpha from animation.
Basic translate animation is behaving correctly.